# Digital Shower Mixer with diverter(s)

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to supply 3 outlets in a shower from ONE output of a digital mixer. I want to be able to control the flow to each of the outputs individually and balance them as I need.

I've spoken to a number of technical support lines and their initial response has generally been "You can't do that", but with no explanation as to why it's a problem.

When pushed, one person suggested that the control circuit in the mixer MIGHT shut down the mixer if the outlet is constricted too much. The feeling was that it would probably reset itself eventually but it might take a long time and, potentially could cause damage to the mixer if it happened repeatedly. This seems plausible to me.

Does anyone have experience of this or could you give any real reason why manufacturers
are telling people this can't be done?

Comment: More information is needed. Such as mixer model number and characteristics or a pointer to its data sheet.

Comment: @Michael Karas - I can't find the exact model on Mira's site - but assume it's one of the ones on this page: http://www.mirashowers.co.uk/onlinecatalog/results.htm?sectionName=Digital%20showers&gclid=CLLAkNfpusACFQoCwwodCoAAUA#. Do you think some mixers might allow it and others won't?

Comment: First off.....I think your idea to feed three shower heads off one digital mixer is a bad idea. The main reason for saying that is because in all probability you  would be unhappy with the results. The mixer is designed specifically with a particular show head and its flow control in mind. You try to pipe that off to three heads and the resulting flow out of each is likely to be pathetic. Keep in mind also that the piping to a typical shower installation may not even have the flow capacity to support three show heads. The added flow will create a pressure drop that may go (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) below what even the Mira mixer can accept as the minimum input flow and pressure. I can see that your goal is to avoid the exorbitant cost of multiple mixers. However please consider this: With the state of affairs with fresh water supplies dwindling in many parts of the world products like Mira is offering should actually be banned and showers be made less desirable to spend time in as opposed to longer.

Comment: @Michael Karas - thank you for your response. First off, I'm not trying to save money by having less mixers (but that was a good guess and a clever idea!) but I have a complicated reason for wanting to do this which everyone agrees with when I explain it. The alternative is that I have 2 entirely separate shower mixers in one wet room - with their own handset. I can see that the flow rate might be a problem due to the outlet of the mixer being a single 15mm pipe and this will be split between 3 outlets. In reality, it will only be split between 2 of them at any one time. (cont..)

Comment: Our entire plumbing system is mains-pressure and works very well. We have another bathroom with a rain head/riser combination and a diverter - the diverter is able to feed to both outlets at the same time and that works very well indeed. With regard to your water-shortage points - I guess you must be in the US; here in the UK, we, quite literally have more water than we can handle for about 23 months out of 24. Summer is just finishing here and my garden is still soggy from the rain of last winter and _another_ wet summer.

Comment: I will think over the implications of the 1-into-3 flow rate because I've not considered that so far. I don't understand this pressure-drop problem either - shows I'm not a plumber I guess - can you explain this a little more for an amateur please?

Comment: Another complication on this has arisen today. Mira are now suggesting that the internals of the mixer are not designed to withstand mains pressure since water is only expected to flow _through_ it. There are electronically operated shut-off valves _before_ the mixer, but if the output flow is constricted then the pressure will reach mains pressure inside the mixer and it will probably leak and be destroyed.

Comment: While I think it's unlikely that normal mains pressure could damage the mixer when the manifold is closed, you could eliminate this risk by adding a pressure relief valve that bypasses the manifold somehow. This is an unusual application for a pressure valve (they're usually found on hydronic heating systems) but the same principle should apply.

Comment: @ShimonRura Thanks for your comment but things have progressed somewhat since my comment above. I now have a 4 outlet mechanical thermostatic mixer with 1 temperature controller. It works brilliantly. I agree that it seems unlikely that mains pressure could damage a digital mixer valve - but I suppose the fact that Mira themselves choose to have shut-off valves BEFORE the mixer tells you something.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: @FreeMan See my comment above yours. I abandoned the idea of using a digital mixer and went for a 4-outlet mechanical thermostatic mixer instead. So, there isn't really an answer to the question as I asked it, but hopefully it will help people to see that this is a complex area and they shouldn't just assume it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could plumb a 3-outlet manifold feeding 3 individual shower flow controllers. You would end up with the single digital temp/flow controller upstream, then three separate single-handle shower flow controllers downstream.

I have seen a similar set-up, the temp. controller (mixer) is on the backside of the wall so employees only have access and water is kept tepid. Public users control only on/off and flow.

Comment: thank you very much for this information, it sounds very similar to what I'm trying to achieve. My plumber doesn't seem to have any problem with **HOW** to split the feed to 3 valves - I assumed he was just going to create a manifold using t-joints and pipe. It's mainly this attitude that I keep getting from manufacturers (and now Michael Karas here) saying that the mixer will not work properly or may be damaged if I stem the flow downstream. It sounds as though the example you've previously seen does this as a matter of routine, leaving it on all the time...?

Comment: They turn it on at beginning of business daily, but it is not a digital mixer. Just standard mixing valve with an internal pressure-balance feature to prevent scalding. I am not sure if your digital mixer may have some sort of "time out" feature or something?

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. In practice, I think we can easily make sure that we never shut-off all 3 valves at the same time - but I'm sure there will be occasions when it happens and I obviously don't want it to cause damage to the mixer when that happens. By the way, sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Lefty, no worries about the votes, just trying to help each other right? I would not worry about damage to the valve, it will have been designed to protect itself. My concern would be that it would turn itself off.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy. An interesting new bit of information as materialised today - see my own answer to my question.

Comment: My folks have their 3/4 mixing valve (non-digital) installed like this. It works fine. My dad's use case was that he sets his desired temperature once for the entire shower and turns multiple sprayers on/off downstream of it.